# How to dynamically change html content depending on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, php, html, responsive

I want to replace a section of a html(php) for one of two php files based on the screen resolution. The only way i know to get screen resolution is by javascript, I've searched for ways to get javascript variables in a php script but I can't achieve what i want to do.(I need to change the section content dynamically, replacing one of the two php files any time screen resolution reaches a specific value).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: _"replacing one of the two php files..."_ php runs on the server which is very far away from the screen of the computer (Unless it's localhost ofcourse) - Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: I've tried to send the screen resolution from a JS script to a php file using AJAX and then load the php file i want  based on the screen size variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have both HTML code ready, and display the correct one based on the screen resolution. You can use CSS display property for it.

Comment: That's not exactly what i want to do, but something similar to it worked very well, thanks!